# Is there a better way to do this query?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm kind of new to MYSQL, this query works but wonder if there's a more efficient way.
I have 2 tables...**client_table** and **client_skills**. Both tables have a 'client_id' column. I'm trying to select only the clients that match all of the requested skill code and types

This is what I first tried... (doesn't work unless you change AND to OR)

```
SELECT * FROM client_table
LEFT JOIN client_skills ON client_table.client_id = client_skills.client_id
WHERE (skill_code='97' AND skill_type='0')
AND (skill_code='65' AND skill_type='0')
AND (skill_code='23' AND skill_type='5')
```

Then I tried this... (which works and returns the results I want it to)

```
SELECT * FROM client_table
WHERE client_id IN 
(SELECT client_id FROM client_skills WHERE (skill_code='97' AND skill_type='0'))
AND client_id IN
(SELECT client_id FROM client_skills WHERE (skill_code='65' AND skill_type='0'))
AND client_id IN
(SELECT client_id FROM client_skills WHERE (skill_code='23' AND skill_type='5'))
```

But if there is a shorter or more efficient way to do that I'd love to learn it.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I am fairly certain of why the first query doesn't work. It is trying to find rows in the client_skill table where skill_code = 97 AND 65 - which is impossible as it can only have 1 value

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @mdml: indeed, I wonder what *is* on-topic these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 1st query modified using `OR` is not bad. and you can do with `UNION`:

```
SELECT client_id FROM client_skills WHERE (skill_code='97' AND skill_type='0')
UNION
SELECT client_id FROM client_skills WHERE (skill_code='65' AND skill_type='0')
UNION
SELECT client_id FROM client_skills WHERE (skill_code='23' AND skill_type='5')
```

### EDITED

you can accomplish something like this. `SELF JOIN` is required. (not tested on you data):

```
SELECT t1.client_id
FROM client_skills t1 JOIN client_skills t2 ON t1.client_id = t2.client_id
            AND t1.skill_code='97' AND t1.skill_type='0'
            AND t2.skil_code='65' AND t2.skill_type='0'
    JOIN client_skills t3 ON t3.client_id = t1.client_id
            AND t3.skil_code='23' AND t3.skill_type='5'
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way of doing AND instead of OR?

Comment: @user3034654 aha! you are looking for client_id matches all three conditions! wait a minute.

Comment: @user3034654 see my updates. is this what you want? if not, you need to provide more Information about what you want. sample data and sample output.

Comment: Thanks terrific! I'd up-vote but I need 7 more reputation before I'm allowed!

Answer (score 0):

the second one is slower than the first one since you are doing 4 queries, so between those two example just go with the first one with OR instead of AND.

There may be better/faster queries, but that depends on the requirements and your table's indexes

For example, do you really need skill_type? can you have two skills with the same code and different type? if all skill codes are different, just do:

```
SELECT * FROM client_table
LEFT JOIN client_skills ON client_table.client_id = client_skills.client_id
WHERE skill_code IN ('97','65','23')
```

if you have an index on skill_code then the query would be faster too

EDIT: ok, now I understand your question, you need at least 2 queries, one to get all client ids that matches the tree skills and one to get clients with those ids, try this:

```
SELECT * from client_table WHERE client_id IN (
  SELECT client_id FROM client_skills WHERE (skill_code='97' AND skill_type='0') OR 
  (skill_code='65' AND skill_type='0') OR (skill_code='23' AND skill_type='5')
  GROUP BY client_id HAVING count(*) = 3)
```

what you are doing there is:

1. get all client_skills records the matches any of your three desired skills
2. group them by client_id
3. select only the client_id for groups that has exactly 3 records (it means those groups have all three skills)
4. select all clients who's ids are in the ids returned by the subquery

I think that's be fastest approach, only 2 queries, I don't think it can be done with just one query

NOTE: that query is not tested, it's the idea, you may need to play a little with HAVING and GROUP_BY

Comment: This one would work fine if the skill_type was encoded in the skill_code column and OR was okay, but alas it isn't! There is a primary key in client_skills but it isn't used for anything. Even if I used primary key to identify skills and did away with the skill_code and skill_type columns, how would I select with AND instead of OR?

Comment: Hmm ideally I suppose I'd use primary key ID and have another table to define which IDs belong to which skill type. But I wanted to not over-complicate things and keep the skill IDs short in length. But even if I used the primary key how would I select using AND instead of OR?

Comment: So you looking for clients with all those 3 (skill_code,skill_type)?

Comment: Ah that sub-query you've done is great as it is just one subquery instead of several! I would up-vote but I need 7 more reputation points!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're asking for since you wanted to use `AND` instead of `OR`
[sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac0d6/6/0) in my example only **Jeff** has all 3 skills (of that skill_code and skill_type)

```
SELECT c.*
FROM client_table c,
     client_skills s1,
     client_skills s2,
     client_skills s3
WHERE
      c.client_id = s1.client_id AND s1.skill_code=97 AND s1.skill_type=0
  AND c.client_id = s2.client_id AND s2.skill_code=65 AND s2.skill_type=0
  AND c.client_id = s3.client_id AND s3.skill_code=23 AND s3.skill_type=5
```

It's the same logic as your second query.

Comment: you might want to put single quotes around the 97,65,23, and 0,0,5 values if your data is in fact some sort of string and not numbers, in my example they're all `int`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    client_table.*
    ,SUM(
        IF( skill_code='97' AND skill_type='0' ,1 ,0 )
        +
        IF( skill_code='65' AND skill_type='0' ,1 ,0 )
        +
        IF( skill_code='23' AND skill_type='5' ,1 ,0 )
    ) AS skill_code_type_count
FROM
    client_table
    LEFT JOIN client_skills ON client_table.client_id = client_skills.client_id
GROUP BY
    client_table.client_id
HAVING
    skill_code_type_count >= 3
```